# Send modified data to serializer in DRF API

Tags: python, django, view, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a Django Rest Framework API.

I have a model like so:

```
class Expression(models.Model):
    expression = models.TextField()
    result = models.IntegerField()
```

My serializer is like so:

```
class ExpressionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self):
        self.operator_mapping = {
            "add": " + ",
            "minus": " - ",
            "divide": " / ",
            "multiply": " * "
        }
        self.data = None

    class Meta:
        model = Expression
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        expression = self.context.get('expression', None)
        result = self.context.get('result', None)

        expression_obj = Expression.objects.create(expression=expression, result=result)

        return expression_obj
```

My view calls two function, evaluate_expression and expression_to_string, to modify the data I send to my serializer:

```
class ExpressionAPIView(APIView):

    queryset = Expression.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExpressionSerializer

    def __init__(self):
        self.operator_mapping = {
            "add": " + ",
            "minus": " - ",
            "divide": " / ",
            "multiply": " * "
        }


    def get(self, request):
        return Response({'data': request.data})

    def post(self, request):
        root = etree.XML(request.data['expression'])

        result = self.evaluate_expression(root)[0]

        exp_parsed = self.expression_to_string(root) + f" = {result}"

        serializer_data = request.data.get('expression', {})

        serializer_context  = {
            'expression': result,
            'result': exp_parsed
        }

        serializer = self.serializer_class(
            data=serializer_data,
            context=serializer_context
        )

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()

        return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I have a TypeError

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'data'
```

and I'm clearly not sending the right data to the serializer.

Comment: I don't see any usage of `operator_mapping` variable...Am I missing something?

Comment: Hey yeah it's used in the two functions that aren't shown - sorry included here by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ExpressionSerializer` where you have inherited from `ModelSerializer` you have not preserved the `ModelSerializer.__init__()` behaviour.

You should add `super(ExpressionSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)` like in the following example.

```
class ExpressionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.operator_mapping = {
            "add": " + ",
            "minus": " - ",
            "divide": " / ",
            "multiply": " * "
        }
        super(ExpressionSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Expression
        fields = "__all__"

    def create(self, validated_data):
        expression = self.context.get('expression', None)
        result = self.context.get('result', None)

        expression_obj = Expression.objects.create(expression=expression, result=result)

        return expression_obj
```

This ensure that during the initialization you are running the `ModelSerializer.__init__()` method.  The `*args, **kwargs` function arguments are there to accept **any** variables that you might pass into that function and forward them to the super method, so you can use it just like a regular `ModelSerializer` and extend it with your own additional arguments and code.

Comment: This solves one problem, but I'm still having trouble passing my data to the serializer

Comment: In the admin I get the error no such column: expressions_expression.result, and in my api frontend I have {
    "non_field_errors": [
        "Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str."
    ]
}

Comment: Are you sending up a json object with an "expression" key/value or a plain string?

Comment: expression is a string and result is an integer? But I thought I was specifying format in the context?

Comment: Also serializer_context = {
            'expression': exp_parsed,
            'result': result
        } - I had them the wrong way round

Comment: Ok I figured it out - I needed to just do serializer_data = {'expression': exp_parsed, 'result': result} and there was no need to give the context